# Appending to SQL Database if not exists statement

Tags: sql

I currently have this code to filter out data to anothertable:

```sql
SELECT sym,
       tstamp,
       COUNT(*) AS trades
FROM datas
GROUP BY sym,
         tstamp
HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300)
INSERT INTO tradecounts
```

Which works fine, however I think it would be more effeicient to just append the new data that is not already in there? I am trying to use this code to do so with no luck:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT sym,
                     tstamp,
                     COUNT(*) AS trades
              FROM datas
              GROUP BY sym,
                       tstamp
              HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300)
    INSERT INTO tradecounts
```

I'm sure this is fairly simple but I am new to SQL language(just started today). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and if you have any good resources for learning query language I would love to see. Thanks!

Comment: Don't tag 4 completely RDBMS. Tag the RDBMS you are using, and ***only*** that RDBMS.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also, some *good* formatting really making your SQL far more readable.

Comment: @Larnu Okay, sorry about that!

Comment: Just wanted to add for anyone who may be new to SQL like me and are looking for a good resource I just came across https://sqlbolt.com . It is perfect for someone just starting out!

Answer (score 0):

Something more like this, perhaps:

```
      WITH x AS(
          SELECT sym,
                 tstamp,
                 COUNT(*) AS trades
          FROM datas
          GROUP BY sym,
                   tstamp
          HAVING COUNT(tstamp) > 300)
     )
     INSERT INTO tradecounts
     SELECT x.* 
     FROM
       x LEFT JOIN tradecounts t ON x.sym = t.sym AND x.tstamp = t.tstamp
     WHERE
       t.sym IS NULL
```

Though what you mean by "already there" will define how you structure the ON clause - i've guessed that it is "sym and tstamp pair do not exist in the destination table"